# Most efficient way to randomly sample directory in Python

Tags: python, performance, file, random

I have a directory with millions of items in it on a fairly slow disk. I want to sample 100 of those items randomly, and I want to do it using a `glob` as well.

One way to do it is to get a glob of every file in the directory, then sample that:

```
files = sorted(glob.glob('*.xml'))
file_count = len(files)
random_files = random.sample(
    range(0, file_count),
    100
)
```

But this is really slow because I have to build up the big list of millions of files, which has to do a lot of disk crawling.

Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't hit the disk as much? It doesn't have to be a perfectly distributed sample or even do exactly 100 items, provided it's fast.

I'm thinking that:

- Maybe we can use the inodes to be faster?
- Maybe we can select items without knowing the entirety of what's on disk?
- Maybe there's some shortcut that can make this faster.

Comment: Does the directory change that often? If not, store the file list in another file and use that for your random sampling.

Comment: @BrentWashburne It doesn't change a ton, but I'd rather avoid the clutter if a technical solution is possible.

Comment: Do the filenames follow a pattern?  If the first character is a letter in [a-z], then you can choose a random letter to start the glob and choose one at random.  Repeat for 100 files.

Comment: That's an idea, but alas, not really.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.listdir` instead of glob. It's twice as fast for this.

```
import glob, random, os,  time

n, t = 0, time.time()
files = sorted(glob.glob('tmp/*'))
file_count = len(files)
print(file_count)
random_files = random.sample(range(0, file_count), 100)
t = time.time() - t 
print "glob.glob: %.4fs, %d files found" % (t, file_count)

n, t = 0, time.time()
files = sorted(os.listdir("tmp/" ))
file_count = len(files)
print(file_count)
random_files = random.sample(range(0, file_count), 100)
t = time.time() - t 
print "os.listdir: %.4fs, %d files found" % (t, file_count)
```

Output

```
glob.glob: 0.6782s, 124729 files found
os.listdir: 0.3183s, 124778 files found
```

Note, if there was some information about the file names that would allow you to randomly generate them that would be the way to go. Or if you can rename the files into a format suitable for random sampling that would also work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this, but I did need the globbing, which will probably add some overhead back into `listdir`.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe we can use the inodes to be faster?

not inodes, but directory entries, you don;t want to call
`stat()` on each file

> Maybe we can select items without knowing the entirety of what's on disk?

Yep, that's the plan. Open directory, read directory entries, sample 100 out of million and only then get to the files

In C this would be `opendir()/readdir()` calls

In python similar calls are performed by `scandir`, which should be included in Python 3.5 RTL. If not, get it from https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir

UPDATE

Link to Opengroup docs wrt `opendir()/readdir()`:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html